# Is there a way to see the analytics to a Google form even if summary is not posted yet?

Tags: google-forms

Im trying to see who will win homecoming representative because im impatient

Ive already tried /viewanalytics and trackyourform.com none have worked ive been searching the internet for like hours and cant seem to find one that i have not already tried

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways of seeing the results of Form submissions.

- within the Form: if you can edit the form, then you can view a summary of the "Responses"
- from a linked Sheet: if the form is linked to a sheet, and if you have permissions to view the sheet, then you can view the Form Responses.